# How to restrict amount of requests? Django

Tags: python, django

How to restrict amount of requests for certain view and user?
Suppose to be a build-in way...

Comment: Related:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376072/limit-number-of-views-per-day-in-django

Comment: And also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603340/track-the-number-of-page-views-or-hits-of-an-object

Answer (score 2):

try to look at django-piston. it is a REST API framework for django.
there is a throtling decorator. it should be feasible to steal it (get inspired)
for your project.

https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#throttling

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your need is related to authentication ,
if it's the case you can have a look at [django-axes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-axes/1.2.1-rc1)