# how implement an efficient visits counter per page?

Tags: django, counter, hitcounter

how implement an efficient visits counter per page? I've marketplace platform, but not a visits counter per product page, then, this is my question.
what's is the better algorithm for implement this?

I not think that this alghoritm is the better "update product set product.visits = (product.visits + 1) where ..."

then, how?

I'm accept sugestions

Google Analytics?
third party solutions?
Alghoritm?

thanks everyone

Was developed in Django

Comment: Does this thread help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603340/track-the-number-of-page-views-or-hits-of-an-object

Answer (score 0):

"Visits counters" can really *hammer* a page because a page can be accessed so many times (per second).  Also, they tend to over-state the desired result for the same basic reason.  (Your database load sails through the rafters ...)

I've had the most success using post-processing of the server access logs.  (Of course there are plenty of existing tools.)  You'll find that you want to *filter* this raw data to pick out what's the most "business meaningful" result for your particular case.