# Logging User statistics in Django

Tags: python, django, pip, django-request

I am using Django's auth_user model and wanted to log the user activities(accessed page details) in my table. I explored and figured out to use django-request module. I have installed django-request 1.5.2 for django 1.8 version. I'm getting this error

```
"NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/pkg/software/python/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_request-1.5.2-py3.6.egg/request/migrations'
```

and also I couldn't find this directory inside my site-packages. What could be the resolution or is there any other module that I can use to log user activities?

Comment: I think you want to know what actions are performed on models, which are mapped to items on GUI, like add/change/del an entry?
Or just page visiting?

Comment: Just the visited pages information is enough for now. So that I can prepare a statistics chart for the distinct users visited site per day.

Comment: similar discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603340/track-the-number-of-page-views-or-hits-of-an-object